# Calculating the maximum size of BLOB in the BLOB column in SQL Server 2016 database

Tags: sql-server, blob

I have a table `Table1` with large amounts of BLOB data in a column `blob_column2`.

I want to calculate the maximum size of the blob (in KBs or MBs) stored in this column.

I need this input for migrating the data.

Can someone help with the query to calculate the maximum size of the blob?

The SQL Server database version is 2016 (v13.0).

Comment: Are you asking to find the size of the largest blob? Did you try `select max(len(thatfield)) from thattable`? Or DATALENGTH ?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: since the OP talks about "blob" data - it might not be a string - therefore, I'd suggest using `DATALENGTH` rather than `LEN` to get the size in bytes

Comment: Answer is easy to find with a bit of research

Comment: I was already writing this. It's unclear what the question is though - was no attempt made to call `MAX(DATALENTH(field))` ? Or was there a problem? Or is the real question how to format the value to KBs (a simple division). Or does the user ask the *total* size of the blobs but used the wrong expression?

Answer (score 1):

The question is badly worded and since no attempt is shown, one can only guess what's being asked

You may be asking how to find the larges (maximum) blob size. Finding the maximum is done with `MAX`:

```
SELECT MAX(DATALENGTH(BlobField)) 
FROM ThatTable
```

That's not very useful for migration, unless you migrate to a database where blobs have length restrictions like MySQL, where BLOB is just 65KB. The equivalent to `varchar(max)` is `LONGBLOB`. There may be more issues from missing features like FILESTREAM storage.

Or you may be asking for the *total* size of all BLOBs, which is useful in storage calculations:

```
SELECT SUM(DATALENGTH(BlobField)) 
FROM ThatTable
```

You can calculate multiple statistics at once:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(DATALENGTH(BlobField)) as TotalSize, 
    SUM(DATALENGTH(BlobField))/1024.0 as TotalSizeKB, 
    MAX(DATALENGTH(BlobField)) as MaxSize,
    MAX(DATALENGTH(BlobField))/1024.0 as MaxSizeKB,
    AVG(DATALENGTH(BlobField)) as AvgSize,
    AVG(DATALENGTH(BlobField))/1024.0 as AvgSizeKB,
FROM ThatTable
```

Keep in mind that everyone except storage vendors defines 1 KB=1024 bytes. That includes file system creators. Storage vendors define it as 1000 bytes